# PHP not finding some records

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Newbie here with a PHP/SQLSRV issue.  I have a PHP page that generates a SQL query (sample below):

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);  
if($conn == false)  
  die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));

$tsql = "SELECT ROUTEID,QTY,ITEMID,INVENTTRANSREFID FROM WMSORDERTRANS WHERE ROUTEID LIKE '%" . $routeID . "%' ORDER BY ROUTEID";
$getRouteInfo = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql); 
if ($getRouteInfo) {
  $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $getRouteInfo );
  $counter = 0;
  if ($rows === true) {
    while ($row =sqlsrv_fetch_array($getRouteInfo,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $counter++;
      echo $row['ROUTEID']."<BR>";
    }
    echo ("COUNT=" . $counter . "<BR><HR>");
  } else {
    echo "There are no rows. <br />";
  }
} else {
  echo ("Something failed in SQLSRV_QUERY<BR>");
}
```

When executed in PHP, the count comes back as 603 rows.
If I copy/paste that exact same query into SQL Management Studio I get 9562 rows.

I have no idea why the same query results in such a drastic difference in row counts.
Any suggestions on what/where I should be looking to locate why such a discrepancy?

I've changed the query to use both a "LIKE" wildcard and explicit ROUTEID targets.  Some routeid's return rows, others don't when querying via PHP but the same ROUTEID shows up when using management studio.

I also setup a connection between Excel and the database.  The excel queries match what I see in Management Studio so my PHP seems to be the anomaly.

I expect the PHP query to return the same result as Excel or Management Studio gets but not sure what I'm missing to get the varied result.

Web Server: IIS on Windows Server 2016
SQL Server: SQL Server 2008 R2
PHP: 7.3.3
SQLSRV_DRV: 5.6.1

Comment: Upgrade PHP to 7.3.3 and MS SQLSRV_DRV to 5.6.1 with same result in query row counts.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a data issue in the DB.  Did a re-copy of the production database to test and now the web server returns the number of rows in PHP to match what management studio sees.  No clue why management studio could see the records and PHP query couldn't but a refresh of the database seems to have cleared it up.